# Stopping a Sound from other Tab in Titanium Appcelerator

Tags: ios, variables, audio, titanium

I am trying to control a sound (**Titanium.Media.Sound**) played in one tab, from another tab.

I would like to send commands like `sound.stop()`, `sound.play()` to the other tab. But I don't know how to access the variable that is in the **other tab** (*.js file*).

Someone knows how to do it, while respecting the best practices?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

### tab1.js, which has the sound:

```
var sound = Ti.Media.createSound({
    url: file
});
Ti.App.addEventListener('playSound', function(evt) {
    sound.play();
});
Ti.App.addEventListener('stopSound', function(evt) {
    sound.stop();
});
```

### tab2.js, which controls the sound:

```
Ti.App.fireEvent('playSound');
Ti.App.fireEvent('stopSound');
```